# MS Azure bot service Slack bot integration issue

Tags: azure, slack, slack-api, azure-bot-service

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I've got "Sad bot is sad because An error occurred processing the request. Please resubmit Slack credentials." issue during Slack authorization of my NLSQL application created on Azure Bot service (Please find also print-screen of an issue).

I've tried to resubmit same credentials with no success.
Please let me know any ideas how to solve this issue and integrate my app to Slack?

[validation issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgmri.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On Slack app select the OAuth & Permissions tab.

Click Add a new Redirect URL.

Enter https://slack.botframework.com BUT NOT https://slack.botframework.com/dev/validate

https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot&client_id=337679718484.338671411941&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fslack.botframework.com%2fHome%2fauth&state=nlsql